# Evaluate two rows independently of one another in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to evaluate 2 rows independently. e.g. check if row1=4 `AND` row2 is NOT equal to 2

The query I have is not working. I think its because I'm saying the interface name must be two values at once. Can I do a union here? or does that not apply?

```
SELECT I.DisplayName, I.Status FROM Interfaces AS I

WHERE  ( I.[InterfaceName] = 'GigabitEthernet1/0/2'  AND  I.[Status] = '4' ) AND  ( I.[InterfaceName] = 'GigabitEthernet1/0/1' AND I.[Status] != '2' )
```

Here is a table sample of these two items.

[image: Table Sample]

Comment: Please provide DDL/DML for your example data. You can do so using table variable(s) like `DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(10), ...); INSERT INTO @Table (Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES (1, 'string', ...), (2, 'text', ...), ....`. Please also include your expected output, without using any images.

Comment: Change the `and` between your two parenthetical statements to an `or`

Comment: `InterfaceName` cant be 'GigabitEthernet1/0/2' and 'GigabitEthernet1/0/1' at the same time, so it will always return no row.  It's like you are saying `WHERE 1 = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking into if table has *any* two rows that both match some condition you can do a following:

```sql
create table Interfaces  (InterfaceName nvarchar(100), status varchar(10))

insert into Interfaces (
    InterfaceName, status
)
values  ('GigabitEthernet1/0/2','4')
,   
('GigabitEthernet1/0/1','1')
,   ('GigabitEthernet1/0/3','2')

SELECT  *
FROM    (
    select  *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt
    from    Interfaces i
    WHERE   (
            (I.[InterfaceName] = 'GigabitEthernet1/0/2' AND I.[Status] = '4')
        OR  (I.[InterfaceName] = 'GigabitEthernet1/0/1' AND I.[Status] != '2')
    )
    ) x
WHERE   cnt >= 2
```

The OR matches the conditions you're looking for, the COUNT makes sure you get at least two values.

If you have duplicates and want to make sure you get both interfaces and not just duplicate of one interface, it's a bit more complicated. One solution is:

```sql
insert into Interfaces (
    InterfaceName, status
)
values  ('GigabitEthernet1/0/2','4')
,   ('GigabitEthernet1/0/1','1')
,   ('GigabitEthernet1/0/1','1')
,   ('GigabitEthernet1/0/3','2')

SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt
        FROM    (
            select  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InterfaceName ORDER BY @@SPID) AS rnk
            from    Interfaces i
            WHERE   (
                    (I.[InterfaceName] = 'GigabitEthernet1/0/2' AND I.[Status] = '4')
                OR  (I.[InterfaceName] = 'GigabitEthernet1/0/1' AND I.[Status] != '2')
            )
            ) x
        WHERE   rnk = 1
    ) x
WHERE   x.cnt >= 2
```

`ROW_NUMBER` creates a grouping of rows per Interface, for which we only take one, and then by wrapping it in another `COUNT(*) OVER()` you once again return the two distinct rows